# Behaviour and limits of $f(n+1) = \frac{f^5(n)}{2} - f(n-1)$

Tags: limits, polynomials, dynamical-systems, fractions, limsup-and-liminf

Let $f(0) = 0,f(1) = \frac{1}{2}$

and

$$f(n+1) = \frac{f^5(n)}{2} - f(n-1)$$

where $*^5$ is a power.

Then it seems

$$ \sup f(n) = \lim \sup f(n) = \frac{1}{2}$$

and

$$ \inf f(n) = \lim \inf f(n) = \frac{-1}{2}$$

Is this true ?

How to prove it ?

***background***

Why I wonder about this ?

Well for most values $0<q<1$ I found that

$f(0) = 0,f(1) = q$

and

$$f(n+1) = \frac{f^5(n)}{2} - f(n-1)$$

Then

$$ \sup f(n) = \lim \sup f(n) \neq q$$

and

$$ \inf f(n) = \lim \inf f(n) \neq -q$$

So it seems remarkable that $f(1) = 1/2$ does satisfy it.

Comment: I found the limits to be larger or smaller than $q$ for those wondering. For instance $q =\ln(2)$ gave a larger limit.

Comment: @AnneBauval it is a power. Thanks, I edited.

Comment: hmm seems very much like this one but for a given value instead of an interval : 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349067/supremum-of-a-n-a-n-13-a-n-2